# Split one txt to several txt files with particular name in Python

Tags: python

I have a txt file which looks like:

```
24.03.2016  Peso
27.03.2016  Ruble
18.04.2016  Euro 
17.05.2016  Dollar
16.06.2016  Frank
```

I need to split it in different files, and the name of a new file should be the date, and the stuffing of this file - the rest. For example - the name is  **18.04.2016** and inside the file is **Euro**.

But if its the same month (like 03.2016 here), i need to put it all in one file, with a name of the first date of this month. For example - the name is **24.03.2016**, and inside is **Peso /n Ruble**.

How I can do that? Now i'm only on the step of reading my file line by line:

```
with open("Data.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        read (line)
```

Comment: You could store it in a dictionary with a format such as `{'03.2016': (firstDate, list of names)}`. Then go through each entry in the dictionary and write them out to the respective files.

Comment: I tried to make it with dict(item.split(" ") for item in line.split(":")), but some of my data already have " " in the body (like Peso Ruble Dollar) in one string, so python says ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required. How to be in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Python's [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) function to group lines with a matching month and year from the file. The lambda function uses `split()` twice to extract the month and year, first by splitting each line by the space, and then by taking the first entry and splitting it by a `.` to get the 3 date components and returning the month/ years parts.

Then for each entry in the group you can then create a file based on the filename of the first entry in this group as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby


with open('data.txt') as f_input:
    for k, g in groupby(f_input, lambda x: x.split()[0].split('.')[1:]):
        entries = list(g)
        with open(entries[0].split()[0], 'w') as f_output:
            for line in entries:
                print line
                f_output.write(line.split(' ', 1)[1].lstrip())
```

This would result in the following 4 files being created:

```
24.03.2016
18.04.2016
17.05.2016                    
16.06.2016
```

The `24.03.2016` file for example would contain:

```
Peso
Ruble
```

Note, this assumes your entries in `data.txt` are in chronological order.

Comment: Martin, and if I have a string with full sentence next to the date, for instance, "Peso№  Ruble, Dollar! Frank?"? and i wanna put all this string in my new file?

Comment: I have made the necessary change to the script. I will now write the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
#!python3
import collections

seen = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open("Data.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        date,currency = line.split()
        month = date[3:]

        seen[month].append((date,currency))

for month in seen.keys():
    with open(seen[month][0][0], 'w') as outfile:
        print(file=outfile,
            "\n".join(currency for date,currency in seen[month]))
```

Comment: it says SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg in string print(file=outfile, "\n".join(currency for date, currency in seen[month]))...

Comment: Bummer. You'll have to move the `file=outfile` to the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the months and corresponding data (first date of month, list of currencies) as key, value pairs in a dictionary. Then, you can write the dictionary to files, whose names will be based on the first date of the month and content on remaining values in the list.

```
dict = {}
with open("Data.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        tokens = line.split()
        date = tokens[0]
        names = tokens[1:]
        list_of_names = dict.get(date[3:], [])   # get existing list of names or new list if key does not exist.
        if not list_of_names:
           list_of_names.append(date)
           list_of_names.extend(names)
        else:
           list_of_names.extend(names)
        dict[date[3:]] = list_of_names

for date, list_of_names in dict.iteritems():
  with open(list_of_names[0] +'.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write('\n'.join(list_of_names[1:]))     # write all names in one go
```

Comment: here i got the error that says 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in date, name = line.split(), as i understood that because in some strings i have not only "Date peso" but "Date Peso Ruble Dollar". How could i fix it?:)